# counter part of SseEmitter class in Reactive?

Tags: spring-webflux

I noticed SseEmitter from servlet could be build with an timeout parameter. Then it start subscribe to server event source. But I did not see its counter part in reactive program. The flux itself could provide reactive feature. But the connection will be closed after related object are returned.

May u know is there a class could work like SseEmitter from webflux?